# Overriding interface method- implementation in Superclass

Tags: interface, subclass, superclass, overriding

Is it ok if a  subclass implements an interface and instead of overriding the method it puts the method in the superclass (method with same name and arguments in superclass). [Diagramm 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsFBP.jpg)

Or is it better to implement it like in the following [Diagramm 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa1Lt.jpg) ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it is legal depends on the language you're using.

I see no reason to not implement it as shown in Diagram 2, provided `AbstractSuperClass` fulfills the promise of `interface1`.

This way any other future subclasses of `AbstractSuperClass` would also be able to be type-checked against `interface1`.